# How Much mA dropped in ESP8266-01 Work in LiPo Battery if the WIFI function is continuously on

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, esp32, espressif

I working on the system where ESP8266-01 should continuously on because I want to get the Wi-Fi function on. In that case ,I can't use the Sleep mode which is given in the Esp8266-01 . So, My Question is that "How much will current(mA) dropped if the esp8266-01 continuously on in 4.2 LiPo battery??

Comment: Do you mean - "How much current is being consumed by the ESP8266 while using WiFi? " If that is your question then I would say that it depends on your specific board and if any external loads are present, given this I have found out that it has a current consumption of 400-420mA while using WiFi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you notice, an answer to this question gives you 200-220 mA is the current consumption, which is not wrong but you can see how it varies, so its best to measure it on your own with your particular case

Comment: I took some measurements [here](https://blog.creations.de/?p=149). Please be aware that you can be in Auto Light Sleep mode and still enjoy the occasional Wifi transmission, it will wake up when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer** is - we don't know.

**Longer answer**:
It depends on such factors as:

1. The board circuit (the BBBL (known as The Big Bright Blue LED) on some boards could drain about 10-20ma only by itself)
2. The voltage regulator efficiency
3. The battery controller circuit / quality / keying efficiency.

**The reasonable value** is about 170-220 mA (taken [from the PDF](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), section 5.2) for continuous data transfer.

[image]

**The true solution is**:
Take the ammeter, connect it *in series with the battery* and measure.

Comment: This is misleading in terms of battery guidance. The values in the chart are peaks, lasting only a ms. With a nodeMCU that doesn't sleep, I see ~70ma idle with traffic pushing it to ~87ma, as seen from a voltmeter (averaging out the spikes). Extending distance to the edge of reliability barely increases measured current of traffic: ~95ma. `100ma` is a good (pessimistic) estimation figure with comfortable margins.

Comment: Yeah, 70 ma seems about right, *if* you don't sleep. I took some measurements [here](https://blog.creations.de/?p=149).

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't sleep at all you can count with about 70 mA, with some short spikes when transmitting.

Sleep mode disabled:

[image: No sleep]

(100 mA per division)

But you **don't need to disable sleep mode** completely to use Wifi, you can be in Auto Light Sleep, which I think is the default for Arduino, Non-OS and RTOS.

Auto Light Sleep:

[image: Auto Light Sleep]

(100 mA per division)

The Wifi will automatically wake up to transmit and it will also wake up according to the Access Points DTIM interval to receive (usually every 300 ms). You're looking at about 2 mA baseline consumption plus the Wifi send and receive spikes.

Unfortunately after bootup there is a 10 second interval with full 70 mA consumption before the Auto Light Sleep mode kicks in. That's a significant drain if you have frequent system resets, but it might have been a bug that has been fixed in the meantime. (I took those measurements in 2017 with the Arduino SDK.)

There are [other modes](https://blog.creations.de/?p=149), but these were the ones that matter in your case.

Comment: this is consistent with my simple measurements and experiments